# PCB footprint for USB cord

Tags: pcb-design, usb

Is there an industry standard footprint for attaching a USB cord to a PCB?

USB2.0 connectors list a footprint in the data sheet. USB2.0 cords only show the pinout, the 4 wire colors, and the shield. What is the preferred way to attach them to the board.

Comment: I'm not sure that you really need an answer because you seem to be saying it in your question i.e. *What is the preferred way to attach them to the board* --> use a connector. You probably meant something else but, I thought I'd point out how your question comes across.

Comment: Are you asking how to attach a cable to a board without a connector?

Comment: @Andyaka I'm trying to attach the 4 wires of a USB cord directly to the PCB. Is there a standard layout to do this?

Comment: @vini_i No, and this is also not recommended for mechanical reasons--wires soldered to a board are prone to breaking off. Using a connector is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

##### Not likely

For two reasons:

1. Every product I have seen with a permanently attached USB coord (hand-held scanners, mice, keyboards) has an internal connector invisible to the user. This is a reliability issue and a lot easier to manufacture since the connector is machine soldered. Hand-soldering a wire in the factory is error-prone and time consuming.
2. Since the cable is now soldered to the board it is not interchangeable with anything, so there is no need for a standard layout.

The industry standard is simply *not* to solder the wire directly to the board.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an industry standard footprint for attaching a USB cord to a PCB?

No.

> What is the preferred way to attach them to the board.

There's no preferred way but depends on the application and requirements.

- You may solder the wires on a surface pad on the PCB directly, and cover them with epoxy or something similar.
- You may solder on a through hole pad, and use some epoxy or something similar.
- Or use a connector instead. That's the best way. Select a connector-terminal combination for your mechanical and other requirements.